# What happens if two smart contracts call each other?

Tags: smart-contracts

Simple question. What happens if you have two smart contracts that recursively call each other in such a way that it will never end?

Will those calls just bounce back and forth until one of the contracts runs out of gas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will those calls just bounce back and forth until one of the contracts runs out of gas?

Yes exactly.